# Create Series by applying function over every df column

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, series

Given a `DataFrame`, I'd like to count the number of `NaN` values in each column, to show the proportion as a histogram.

I've come up with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
nan_dict = {}
for col in df:
    nan_dict[col] = df[col].value_counts(dropna=False)[0]
```

and then build the histogram from the dict. This seems really cumbersome; also, it fails when there are no `NaN`s.

Is there a way I could apply `value_counts` along all columns so that I get back a `Series` with `NaN` values per column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3, 4]})
print(dict(zip(df.columns, df.isna().sum())))
```

Prints:

```
{'col1': 0, 'col2': 0}
```

---

For dataframe:

```
   col1  col2
0     1   3.0
1     2   NaN
```

Prints:

```py
{'col1': 0, 'col2': 1}
```